# Struggling with Q promises in Durandal app

Tags: breeze, durandal, q

In my activate method of my viewmodel I have the following code.

```
function activate() {
    var promise = Q.all([datacontext.getManufacturers(manufacturers)]);
    logger.log('Frames View Activated', null, 'frames', false);
    return promise;
}
```

And in my data context code I have

```
var getManufacturers = function (manufacturerObservable) {
    var query = entityQuery.from('Manufacturers')
        .orderBy('name');

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
         if (manufacturerObservable) {
             manufacturerObservable(data.results);
         }
         log('Retrieved [Manufacturer] from remote data source',
             data, false);
    }
};
```

I would expect the way the promises are set up that the manufacturers would be retrieved and then the activation method would finish.  I would expect the 'Retrieved [Manufacturer] from remote data source' log message to occur before the 'Frames View Activate' log message, but in fact the opposite happens.  How can I get my data retrieval to finish before the activate method finishes?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need Q at all in this case. breeze data manager returns its own promise.

```
function activate() {
    logger.log('Frames View Activated', null, 'frames', false);
    return datacontext.getManufacturers(manufacturers);
}
```

This make sure that before activate function returns getManufacturer function has finished.

However, if you want Frames View Activated to displayed after the retrieved message then you can either use `promise.spread.then(function() {logger.log('Frames View Activated', null, 'frames', false); })` or `promise.then(function() {logger.log('Frames View Activated', null, 'frames', false); })`

Comment: Even when I do var promise = Q.all([datacontext.getManufacturers(manufacturers)]).then(logger.log('Frames View Activated', null, 'frames', false));          
        return promise;  The log message for loading still occurs before the log message in getManufacturers.

Comment: Should be .then(function(){logger.log('Frames View Activated', null, 'frames', false);}); // You should pass the function that will be called "then", not call it.

Comment: As Pawel said, you will have to add the logger message inside .then(). I edited the answer for future references.

Comment: And why `Q.all([datacontext.getManufacturers(manufacturers)])`? Use `Q.all` to wait upon multiple promises. Here you only have one. Should be: `datacontext.getManufacturers(manufacturers).then(function(){logger.log('Frames View Activated', null, 'frames', false); });`

Answer (score 2):

The problem here seems to be that while breeze uses the Q deferred/promise implementation, Durandal uses the JQuery deferred/promise implementation.

By mixing the two you may get some problems.

If you read the Durandal documentation, they have a solution for making Durandal use Q instead of JQuery so that you get a consistendt deferred/promise solution for your Application.

Comment: Jorn, I used the spinet to replace the default Promises with Q promises and it's a great help.

Comment: system.defer = function (action) {
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            action.call(deferred, deferred);
            var promise = deferred.promise;
            deferred.promise = function () {
                return promise;
            };
            return deferred;
        };